# Declaring a newcommand for a single letter in mathcal

Tags: macros, amsmath, mathcal

I am trying to enter a command that references the `\mathcal` font for single letter in LaTeX. Below is what I am trying and it doesn't seem to work, would appreciate any help.

```
 \newcommand {\until} {\mathcal {u} }
```

I believe by doing this, when I type `\until` it should apply the `u` in the desired font.

Comment: It does, but the mathcal alphabet is only available in uppercase so you get a square cap symbol. Try it with U instead.

Comment: Yeah lowercase letter seems to be the fault, thanks.

Comment: You can have lower case calligraphic letters with some fonts, e.g., Zapf chancery: `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it} ... $\mathpcz{u}$`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use capital letter(s) `U`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newcommand{\until} {\mathcal{U} }

\begin{document}

$\until$
\end{document}
```

[image]